# how can i fetch data stats value

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

i have json file in an api source, The json output is as below.

```js
{
    "data": {
        "metadata": { },
        "segments": [
            {
                "type": "overview",
                "attributes": {},
                "expiryDate": "2021-07-03T00:25:07.8647619+00:00",
                "stats": {
                    "timePlayed": {
                        "rank": null,
                        "percentile": 93,
                        "displayName": "Time Played",
                        "displayCategory": "General",
                        "category": "general",
                        "metadata": {},
                        "value": 6635877,
                        "displayValue": "1,843h 17m",
                        "displayType": "TimeSeconds"
                    },
                    "score": {
                        "rank": null,
                        "percentile": 85,
                        "displayName": "Score",
                        "displayCategory": "General",
                        "category": "general",
                        "metadata": {},
                        "value": 210790,
                        "displayValue": "210,790",
                        "displayType": "Number"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
            "availableSegments": [],
                "expiryDate": "2021-07-03T00:25:07.8647619+00:00"
    }
}
```

I want to get the data > segments > stats values ​​in this json output using fetch method. My Codes;

```js
fetch(csgo2, {"headers": {"TRN-Api-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}).then(res => res.json()).then(body => {
              
                const { timePlayed, score} = body.data.segments[0];  
                
                console.log(timePlayed.value)//undefined always output console.

                
            })
```

I'm trying to get the data > segments > score or timesplayed value as in the code block, but I keep getting the undefined error from the console.

what i want to do is get the score or timesplayed value

Comment: Looks like it should be `const { timePlayed, score} = body.data.segments[0].stats;`

Comment: this worked for me thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you should use `body.data.segments[0].stats`. The body is an object with a data property, not the data property itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29320804)

Comment: @Tom this is a valid answer from my standpoint. Where is the issue here?

Comment: Please also add details around why the given solution works and above one dind't work.